# Xamarin IOS Buid Faild <<Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1029, 3): [MSB6006] "dsymutil" exited with code 1.>>

Tags: ios, xamarin, rider

I think since the last XCode update it is not possible to deploy IOS Apps to the Iphone.
Before everything worked fine.

I get this error Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1029, 3): [MSB6006] "dsymutil" exited with code 1.

On Line 1029:

```
    <!-- run dsymutil on the main bundle -->
    <DSymUtil
        SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)"
        Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true' And '$(MtouchNoDSymUtil)' == 'false' And '$(IsAppExtension)' == 'false'"
        AppBundleDir="$(AppBundleDir)"
        Architectures="$(_CompiledArchitectures)"
        DSymDir="$(AppBundleDir).dSYM"
        Executable="$(_NativeExecutable)"
        ToolExe="$(DSymUtilExe)"
        ToolPath="$(DSymUtilPath)"
    >
    </DSymUtil>
```

Reinstalled Xcode but still run into it.
Tried a new created Application but it also fails to build.

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Working with JetBrainsRider on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today there were new updates for Xamarin and .Net Core and they fixed my Problem, everything works again!

Edit:

now I run

.Net Core: 3.1.201
Xamarin IOS 13.14.139
Xamarin Android 10.2.0
Mono 6.8.0.105

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, which will help more people :)

Comment: @Steffen What versions of Xamarin and .NET Core are you running now?